# Updating a multi-select list from an array using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu, multi-select

I have a multi-select dropdown list which needs to be updated automatically.   More specifically, I want to select options using jquery if the value of the option in the dropdown list appears in an array.

I have tried various approaches that that I found on Stack Exchange but none appear to be working.  When I use console.log, it is clear that the value is found because it correctly follows the right "if" statement path.

However, when I look at my dropdown list nothing is selected.

My javascript/jquery code is here below.  Any help would be appreciated.

```
final_participants_array=data[0].final_participants_val;
final_participants_array=final_participants_array.split(',');
console.log(final_participants_array);



setTimeout(function(){
 $("#participants option").each(function(){
 var $this_val=$(this).val();                                                                                                       
 if (jQuery.inArray($this_val,final_participants_array)!==-1){                                                   
    console.log($this_val);                                                    
    $("#participants option[value='" + $this_val +"']").prop("selected", 
  true);
   }
});
}, 1000);
```

As I mentioned, when I then look at my multi-select list, there is nothing selected.  Do I need to refresh my multi-select list or something?

Comment: You have a typo in your selector.  `$("#participants option [value='" + $this_val +"']")`.  The space between option and the attribute selector makes it try to look for a child.  But there is not a child.  Remove that space.  Voting to close as a typo.

Comment: Also, you don't need to do that selector at all.  `this` is where the value came from, and thus it's the `option`.  `this.selected = true` and call it a day

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/pmfad94j/1/ <= you can also reduce your logic with a filter

Comment: Thanks Taplar.  I have removed the extra space.   Still now showing as selected.  I also tried your approach with filter and it likewise did not work.  I am not getting errors with either approach but it is just not updating the checkboxes in the dropdown.  Do I need to refresh or use ajax to actually see this change?